# How to checkout a case sensitive SVN source code branch to a case insensitive system?

Tags: svn, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I am working on a Macbook system , which is formatted as a case insensitive system. The issue is that, I need to check out a SVN branch which has some case sensitive files in it. 
Example:

```
inbuilt-file.c
InBuilt-File.c
```

How do I checkout this branch when both the files are in the same folder? When I try and checkout, it gives me an error stating that an unversioned file of the name already exists.

Comment: suggest using Vagrant / Virtual Box and run a Linux VM

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ways that immediately come to mind are:

1. Stop using case sensitive file names. There really is no reason to have Foo.c and foo.c being different things.
2. Stop using a case insensitive file system. You *can* format HFS+ volumes to be case-insensitive on Mac OS X although Adobe Creative Suite and World of Warcraft will moan about it.
3. Check it out onto a DMG file formatted with case-sensitive HFS+. Create it in Disk Utility or with a command like this: `hdiutil create -size 100m -fs "Case-sensitive HFS+" -volname CaseSensitive CaseSensitive.dmg`
4. A slightly hare-brained idea: [use git svn](http://flavio.castelli.name/howto_use_git_with_svn) and write some hooks that'd automatically translate the file names where the case sensitivity is an issue into a modified filename that follows a particular standard when you check-out and then checks them back in again with the *right* filename. Of course, this would break your build scripts and dependencies and so on because the file would *still* not have the right name. So you'd then need to start a branch, which gets you back to having to use something like git svn. This seems unnecessarily painful compared to (1).

Comment: The first point is only valid for case insensitive languages. Foo.c and foo.c might not be any different but Foo.java and foo.java are.

Comment: a part of the two first answers, which are not answers (people aren't always in control of these conditions), solution 3 is quite smart.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem recently (running Windows), and was not able to figure it out.

For Mac users, someone had written instructions though:

1. Use apple's Disk Utility app to create a new sparse disk image of type Mac OS Extended (case-sensitive,journaled)
2. Mount the new disk image
3. check out pet sources to this image

Answer (score 1):

Lauri Lehtinen's answer looks good. However, if you need to work with the files in a case insensitive system you'll have to rename them anyway. You can rename them in the repository before you check them out using the `svn move` command.

```
$ svn help rename
move (mv, rename, ren): Move and/or rename something in working copy or repository.
usage: move SRC... DST
```